# Optimizing this stacking of N weight-sharing Keras models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have two Keras (Tensorflow backend) models, which are stacked to make a combined model:

- `small_model` with `In: (None,K), Out: (None,K)`
- `large_model` with `In: (None,N,K), Out: (None,1)`
- `combined_model` (`N x small_model -> large_model`) with `In: (None,N,K), Out: (None,1)`

`large_model` needs `N` stacked outputs from `small_model` as input.

I can define `N` `small_model`s, which share weights, then concatenate their outputs (technically, I need to stack them), and then send that to `large_model`, as in the code below.

**My problem** is that I need to be able to do this for very large `N` (`> 10**6`), and that my current solution uses a lot of memory and time when creating the models, even for `N ~ 10**2`.

I'm hoping that there is a solution which sends the `N` data points through `small_model` in parallel (like what is done when giving a batch to a model), collects those points (with the Keras history, so that backprop is possible) and sends that to `large_model`, without having to define the `N` instances of `small_model`. The listed input and output shapes for the three models should not change, but other intermediate models can of course be defined.

Thank you.

**Current unsatisfactory solution** (assume that `small_model` and `large_model` already exist, and that `N,K` are defined):

```
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K

def build_small_model_on_batch():

    def distribute_inputs_to_small_model(input):
        return [small_model(input[:,i]) for i in range(N)]

    def stacker(list_of_tensors):
        return K.stack(list_of_tensors, axis=1)

    input = Input(shape=(N,K,))
    small_model_outputs = Lambda(distribute_inputs_to_small_model)(input)
    stacked_small_model_outputs = Lambda(stacker)(small_model_outputs)

    return Model(input, stacked_small_model_outputs)

def build_combined():

    input = Input(shape=(N,K,))
    stacked_small_model_outputs = small_model_on_batch(input)
    output = large_model(stacked_small_model_outputs)

    return Model(input, output)

small_model_on_batch = build_small_model_on_batch()
combined = build_combined()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with a [`TimeDistributed`](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#timedistributed) layer wrapper:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, TimeDistributed
from keras.models import Sequential, Model

N = None  # Use fixed value if you do not want variable input size
K = 20

def small_model():
    inputs = Input(shape=(K,))
    # Define the small model
    # Here it is just a single dense layer
    outputs = Dense(K, activation='relu')(inputs)
    return Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

def large_model():
    inputs = Input(shape=(N, K))
    # Define the large model
    # Just a single neuron here
    outputs = Dense(1, activation='relu')(inputs)
    return Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

def combined_model():
    inputs = Input(shape=(N, K))
    # The TimeDistributed layer applies the given model
    # to every input across dimension 1 (N)
    small_model_out = TimeDistributed(small_model())(inputs)
    # Apply large model
    outputs = large_model()(small_model_out)
    return Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model = combined_model()
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd')
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, None, 20)          0
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_1 (TimeDist (None, None, 20)          420
_________________________________________________________________
model_2 (Model)              (None, None, 1)           21
=================================================================
Total params: 441
Trainable params: 441
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: One final thing (I promise :P): `TimeDistributed` takes a layer as its argument, not a tensor, so what is being wrapped should be `small_model`, as opposed to `small_model()`. The latter gives an error, at least. 

In the same vein, should `outputs` not be `large_model(small_model_out)`, as `TimeDistributed` returns a tensor?

Comment: Well, in this code `small_model` and `large_model` are functions, each returning a `Model` object. `TimeDistributed` can receive a `Layer` or a `Model`, so `TimeDistributed(small_model())(inputs)` means "apply the model created by `small_model()` to every tensor across the dimension 1 of `inputs`". Similarly, in this case `large_model()(small_model_out)` means "take the model created by `large_model()` and apply it to `small_model_out`". The names may not exactly match your code, I just meant to make a simple, self-contained snippet to illustrate the idea.

Comment: Ah, I see the intention now. However, I think your code will generate `N` different instances of `small_model`, thus not making backprop work on the same model (i.e., there is effectively no weight sharing), which is definitely not desired, at least in my case.

Comment: @OfficialThrowaway No, `TimeDistributed` does not make copies of the given layer or model, it only applies it over a dimension. Actually, it cannot possibly make `N` copies, since `N` is unknown (it can be different for each input). Only one instance of the small model is created, with `small_model()`, and passed to `TimeDistributed`, which will "broadcast it" to the whole input.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now!